# Selecting different specific values in dataframe after use replace method

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, replace

Here's my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#create a list of each year where data will be extract

years_list = [2001, 2002, 2008, 2012, 2015,2018, 2020 , 2021]
player_list = ['Mac Jones', 'Aaron Rodgers', 'Deshaun Watson', 'Patrick Mahomes',
                'Josh Allen', 'Ryan Tannehill', 'Drew Bress', 'Russel Wilson',
                'Kirk Cousins', 'Tom Brady', 'Derek Carr']

#selecting stats
cols = ['Player', 'Tm','Cmp%', 'Yds', 'TD', 'Int', 'Y/A', 'Rate', 'G']
df_list = []

#loop for extract data
for year in years_list:
    url_mac = f'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/{year}/passing.htm'
    temp_df = pd.read_html(url_mac)[0][cols]
    temp_df['Season'] = year
    
    df_list.append(temp_df)
    print(f'Collected: {year}')


data_radar = pd.concat(df_list)

#renaming columns
new_columns = data_radar.columns.values
new_columns[-6] = 'y_sack'
data_radar.columns = new_columns

#picking stats
mid_data = pd.DataFrame()
for player in player_list:
    mid_data = mid_data.append(data_radar[data_radar['Player'] == player + '*'])
    mid_data = mid_data.append(data_radar[data_radar['Player'] == player + '*' + '+'])
    mid_data = mid_data.append(data_radar[data_radar['Player'] == player])
    mid_data = mid_data.append(data_radar[data_radar['Player'] == player + '+'])

#relevant stats
cols = ['Cmp%', 'Yds', 'Int', 'Y/A','Rate', 'G', 'Season']
final_data = pd.DataFrame()

#fixing names
mid_data = mid_data.replace({'Tom Brady*':'Tom Brady', 'Aaron Rodgers*':'Aaron Rodgers','Aaron Rodgers*+':'Aaron Rodgers',
                   'Deshaun Watson*':'Deshaun Watson', 'Josh Allen*':'Josh Allen',
                   'Derek Carr*':'Derek Carr','Patrick Mahomes*':'Patrick Mahomes', 'Patrick Mahomes*+':'Patrick Mahomes' })




#Select informations about players and ordering

final_data = mid_data[['Player', 'Tm'] + cols]
final_data.sort_values(by = 'Player', ascending=True)
final_data.drop_duplicates(subset = 'Player')
```

What i want with that code is that my df final_data returns me first season of each player, but that dont work with some players that i needed use replace method.

Where i write to sort_value that's my result, before drop.duplicates()

[image]

My idea was sort these values, then use drop.duplicates() to select just first of each player.

This happen with all players that i needed use replace method. How fix this ?

Comment: if you find the solutions worked for you, you should make sure to accept the solution. This includes your previous posts which you still have not accepted a solution for either [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69284705/how-to-loop-to-scrape-different-pages-with-python)

Comment: Oh! Thank you. I cast my positive vote, but I didn't see that there is an accept button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's quite a few confusing parts of your code. First, if all you are trying to do is get rid of the `'*'` and or `'+'` in the player names, why not just do that as opposed to hard coding each player? Second, your comments don't actually describe what your code is doing. I don't see the point of

```
#Converting colums from object to floats
cols = ['Cmp%', 'Yds', 'Int', 'Y/A','Rate', 'G', 'Season']
final_data = pd.DataFrame()
```

as you are not converting to floats, and `# picking top 10 qb in rating stats in last season + Mac Jones` comment isn't doing what it says either. Very confusing to follow your comments.

Thirdly, if you want the first season of each player, then you need to sort by `'Season'`, so when you drop duplicates of the player name, you can explicitly say to keep the first entry/row of that player, which wil be their first season in the dataframe if you sorted it.

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd


#create a list of each year where data will be extract

years_list = [2001, 2002, 2008, 2012, 2015,2018, 2020 , 2021]
player_list = ['Mac Jones', 'Aaron Rodgers', 'Deshaun Watson', 'Patrick Mahomes',
                'Josh Allen', 'Ryan Tannehill', 'Drew Bress', 'Russel Wilson',
                'Kirk Cousins', 'Tom Brady', 'Derek Carr']

#selecting stats
cols = ['Player', 'Tm','Cmp%', 'Yds', 'TD', 'Int', 'Y/A', 'Rate', 'G']
df_list = []

#loop for extract data
for year in years_list:
    url_mac = f'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/{year}/passing.htm'
    temp_df = pd.read_html(url_mac)[0][cols]
    temp_df['Season'] = year
    
    temp_df = temp_df[temp_df['Player'] != 'Player']
    
    df_list.append(temp_df)
    print(f'Collected: {year}')
data_radar = pd.concat(df_list)


#renaming columns
new_columns = data_radar.columns.values
new_columns[-6] = 'y_sack'
data_radar.columns = new_columns

# Repace * or + with ''
data_radar['Player'] = data_radar['Player'].str.replace(r'\*|\+','')


cols = ['Cmp%', 'Yds', 'Int', 'Y/A','Rate', 'G', 'Season']

#Select informations about players and ordering
final_data = data_radar[['Player', 'Tm'] + cols]
final_data = final_data.sort_values(by = ['Player', 'Season'], ascending=[True,True])
final_data = final_data.drop_duplicates(subset = 'Player', keep='first')
```

**Output:**

```
print(final_data)
                Player   Tm  Cmp%   Yds Int   Y/A   Rate   G  Season
53         A.J. Feeley  PHI  71.4   143   1  10.2  114.0   1    2001
41       A.J. McCarron  CIN  66.4   854   2   7.2   97.1   7    2015
3         Aaron Brooks  NOR  55.9  3832  22   6.9   76.4  16    2001
3        Aaron Rodgers  GNB  63.6  4038  13   7.5   93.8  16    2008
71         Akili Smith  CIN  62.5    37   0   4.6   73.4   2    2001
..                 ...  ...   ...   ...  ..   ...    ...  ..     ...
89       Wayne Chrebet  NYJ   0.0     0   0   0.0   39.6  15    2002
39   Zach Mettenberger  TEN  60.8   935   7   5.6   66.7   7    2015
112        Zach Pascal  IND   0.0     0   0   0.0   39.6  16    2020
27         Zach Wilson  NYJ  55.2   628   7   6.0   51.6   3    2021
105          Zay Jones  BUF   0.0     0   0   0.0   39.6  16    2018

[427 rows x 9 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks, result was not perfect but presented everything that i needed to go on.  These comments was wrong, i already fix this.

Comment: About my comment that you selected, for me was clearly because i already know what the coding was doing. Players that are in player_list finished as top 10 in rating statistics in last season and Mac Jones are the rookie that i want compare. I'll improve this part of my skills, thanks.

Comment: You've idea why my sort.values was not working ?

Comment: ya, when you sort, it wasn't storing the sorted dataframe, just outputing it. so you need to assign it. So would need to change from `final_data.sort_values(by = 'Player', ascending=True)` to `final_data = final_data.sort_values(by = 'Player', ascending=True)`

Comment: you could keep it the way you had it, but then need to add the `inplace=True` parameter. So, `final_data.sort_values(by = 'Player', ascending=True, inplace=True)`. That would work as well

Comment: oh i see, thank you